# Erro NHibernate: No persister for

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

Gostaria de uma ajuda em relação ao erro apresentado quando tento gravar registros com o NHibernate pelo mapeamento XML.

O projeto possui camadas separadas.

No projeto de domínio, está minha entidade:

```
namespace NHibernateTesteWeb.Domain.Entity
{
    public class Company
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

No projeto de acesso a dados está o xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
    namespace="NHibernateTesteWeb.Domain.Entity" assembly="NHibernateTesteWeb">
  <class name="NHibernateTesteWeb.Domain.Entity.Company" table="Company">    
    <id name="Id">
      <column name="Id" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>    
    <property name="Name">
      <column name="Name" length="100" not-null="false" />      
    </property>    
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

e arquivo de configuração do Nhibernate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">
      Server=(localdb)\Projects;initial catalog=TesteHibernate;Integrated Security=True
    </property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping assembly="NHibernateTesteWeb"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Ainda no projeto de acesso a dados está a classe NHibernateHelper:

```
namespace NHibernateTesteWeb.Data.Helper
{
    public sealed class NHibernateHelper
    {
    ...    
        static NHibernateHelper()
        {
            _sessionFactory = new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory();
        }
    }
}
```

Os dois xmls estão com a opção 'Embedded Resource' e 'Copy always'.

Acredito que o erro possa estar relacionado ao fato do NHibernate estar em um projeto, e a entidade em outro. Aparentemente carrega o hibernate.cfg.xml e também o Company.hbm.xml, porém não mapeia a propriedade class do xml para a entidade nele indicada.

Detalhes do erro:

> No persister for: NHibernateTesteWeb.Domain.Entity.Company

A última chamada descrita na pilha de rastreamento:

> at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.GetEntityPersister(String entityName)

Comment: O que `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` retorna? Adcione essa linha `Assembly currentAssem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();` antes do `_sessionFactory = new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory();` e inspecione a retorno. Ele tem que ser `NHibernateTesteWeb`

Comment: NHibernateTesteWeb.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null